# Find exact tangent points of a circle between a plain and circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

There is a circle with $60$ units diameter, which is exactly $35$ units far from a plain. I want to place another circle with $50$ units diameter between them. How can I define exact $A$ and $B$ tangent points as it is shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: By "plain" do you mean "straight line"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is right. Sorry for my English. I am not familair with English geometry terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a horizontal line from the midpoint of the lower circle, going to the left where it meets the line labelled "35". It hits this line 25 units up (since that's the radius of the right-hand circle). Call this intersection $S$.

From $S$ to the circle center above it is $40$ units. From one circle center to the other is $30 + 25 = 55$ units. Hence from $S$ to the lower circle center is a distance $q$ such that 
$$
q^2 + 40^2 = 55^2 \\
q \approx 37.7491722
$$
So the point $B$ is $37.7491722$ units to the right of the place where the "35" line meets the top of the rectangle.

The point $A$ is $30/55$ths of the way from the  center of the top circle to the center of the bottom circle, so $A$ is approximately $\frac{30}{55}37.7491722 \approx 20.59$ to the right of the "35" line, and at height 
$25 + \frac{25}{55}40 \approx 43.18$ (above the top edge of the rectangle).

Comment: a is approximately 37.75. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nope.. I screwed up and took (25/55) times $65$ instead of $40$. Fixed now, and it appears that the height above the rectangle is $43.18$. Your answer of $37.75$ seems quite a bit too small; it'd be right if the two circle had the same diameter, but they don't. I've edited my answer to fix this mistake (and to call a different distance "q" instead of "a", because it might be confused with your "A").

Comment: Sorry, I mean q. On screen Italic q looks like a

Comment: Fixed. I have no idea how I got that earlier value for $q$ --- cut and paste error, I guess. So it looks as if you were exactly right (or off by less than $.001$, anyhow!)

Answer (score 1):

It's trapezoid $O_1O_2BK$, where $O_1O_2=55$, $O_2B=25$ and $O_1K=65$.

Thus, by the Pythagoras theorem $KB=\sqrt{55^2-(65-25)^2}$

Comment: @John Hughes I saw it before. Thank you!